# Unicoin mining doesn't work on iPhone / Chrome

Tags: bug, status-completed, iphone, unicoins

There is a serious bug: I can not mine rocks using Chrome on iPhone!

I hope this will be rectified over the coming weeks.

Comment: 6-8 weeks according to the devs. Until then, [meta-tag:status-deferred]

Comment: Over coming weeks?. I smell something strange....

Comment: I'm fixing this right now (at least for the iPad, I assume it'll be the same).

Comment: Excellent. Can I help pay for the fix using my remaining unicoins?